# Splitting react-router routes in monorepo projects

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I am writing medium-size **React** application and **react-router@v6**, and I can not find an idiom how to write nested routes considering **Nx monorepo** architecture.

What I want:

- Each application/library should define it's independent routing, without leaking abstractions;
- The same rule should apply to modules within single package. Nested routes should belong to very own sub module, not defined in root router
- If there are no matching route, closest parent matching '*' route should handle it (right now it does not).

For reference, **SvelteKit**'s router works exactly as that.

Currently I can achieve (1) and (2), but not (3). Although, react-router documentation does not consider use cases (1) and (2) at all and only have examples of single router file with all project routes, which is not ideal because higher-level routers become dependent on implementation details (nested routes). It sounds like DI principle violation to me.

Would like to hear any advises or patterns. Currently I have this:
In packages/app/src/app/app.tsx:

```js
function App() {
  return <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/settings/*"
        element={
          <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
            <SettomgsPage />
          </Suspense>
        }
      />
      <!-- This will not work for /settings/not-existing-path -->
      <Router path="*" element={<Fallback />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
}
```

In packages/settings/src/lib/index.tsx:

```js
export default function Page() {
  return <Routes>
    <Route path="user/:id" element={<UserSettingsPage />} />
    <!-- All nested Routes need explicit '*' route -->  
  </Routes>
}
```